# Linking two programs together in python

Tags: python

Is there any way that I can link two programs to each other in python. basically I want the program to jump to another program when a button is clicked so that it can all be integrated into one application. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/calling-an-external-command-in-python

Comment: Is the other "program" written in python? If so, you might be able to import its modules and create its objects. What GUI library are you using?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [PyQt](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PyQt), you can use [signals and slots](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/new_style_signals_slots.html) to define a callback function when a certain button is clicked.

You can hide the Ui of the current program and display the Ui of the other program, when the button is clicked.